# @fastify/multipart Cannot read data.fields.username.value

Tags: typescript, fastify, fastify-multipart

I have this simple upload form, I'm using postman to send the file

[image]

the first 4 times I post the same file, everything works as expected but on the 5th time 'data.fields.username' is undefined, even though nothing has changed between requests.

The exact error I get is

```
{
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')"
}
```

when I log out data.fields on the post that fails I get this

[image]

and If I log data.fields.username i get `undefined`

And the code I'm using...

```
async function uploadFile(fastify: any, _options: Object) {
  fastify.register(require("@fastify/multipart"));

  fastify.post(
    "/v1/uploads/uploadFile",
    postOpts,
    async function (request: any, reply: any) {

      const data = await request.file();
      console.log("===============================================");
      console.log(data.fields.username.value); // <=== on the 5th / 6th post this fails
      console.log("===============================================");
      
      const statusCode: number = 201;
      reply
        .code(statusCode)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        .send({ statusCode });
    }
  );
}

const postOpts = {
  schema: {
    summary: "Upload File",
    consumes: ["multipart/form-data"],
    // body: {
    //   type: "object",
    //   properties: {
    //     username: {
    //       type: "string",
    //     },
    //   },
    //   required: ["username"],
    // },
    response: {
      200: {
        type: "object",
        description:
          "The request was successful. The response will contain a JSON body.",
        properties: {
          uploadConfirmed: { type: "boolean" },
          upoadConfirmedTime: { type: "number" },
        },
      },
      400: {
        type: "object",
        description: "The request was invalid and/or malformed.",
        properties: {
          error: { type: "string" },
          statusCode: { type: "number" },
          message: { type: "string" },
        },
      },
      500: {
        type: "object",
        description: "There was an internal error.",
        properties: {
          error: { type: "string" },
          statusCode: { type: "number" },
          message: { type: "string" },
        },
      },
    },
  } as const,
};

export { uploadFile };
```

my tsconfig is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "outDir": "./build" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

I'm running node version `v16.14.0` on a mac

Comment: I think the issue comes from `"target": "es5"` since the modules are designed for most recent node.js versions

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to make sure the file is appended last not first! Grrr

[image]

Comment: did you find the reason for that?