Is there a specific order for appending values in a FormData object that contains a file?
I have a simple Angular component that retrieves a file from an input and sends it to the backend, along with other variables, using FormData.
// uploader.component.html

...other HTML elements

 <div class="file-uploader-container">
    <input (change)="handleFileUpload($event.target.files)" type="file" name="files" #fileField hidden/>
 </div>

So, I listen to the change event of the element, create my FormData by appending the necessary data, and call the storage service.
// uploader.component.ts

handleFileUpload(files: FileList) {
    try {

      this.file = files.item(0) ?? undefined;
      this.filename = this.file?.name;

      if(!this.file) {
        throw new Error('Error during the file upload')
      }

      if(this.allowedTypes.length && !this.allowedTypes.includes(this.fileType!)) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid file format`)
      }

      const form = new FormData();
      form.append('file', this.file); // <-- Causes other variables to be undefined when appended first
      form.append('app_id', environment.app_id);

      this.isUploading = true;

      // * upload file on storage 
      this.storageService.uploadFileOnStorage(form).pipe(
        tap( () => this.isUploading = false)
      ).subscribe({
        next: (uploadedFile) => {
          this.onFileUpload.emit(uploadedFile.file_key);
        },
        error: (error: any) => {
          console.error(error);
          this.swalService.showErrorMesssage("Error during the upload");
          this.clearInput();
        }
      })


    } catch(error: any) {
      this.swalService.showErrorMesssage(error.message);
      this.clearInput();
    }
  }

// upload.service.ts

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { StorageUploadDTO } from '../types/dto/storage-upload.dto';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StorageService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  uploadFileOnStorage(form: FormData) {
    return this.http.post<StorageUploadDTO>(`${environment.storageBackend}/api/v1/file/upload`, form)
  }
}



I noticed that when I append the file first, the other variables that are appended become undefined when I retrieve them on the backend. However, this does not happen when I append the file at the end of the FormData. Why does this happen?

EDIT: 
Here's how I retrieve the two keys from the FormData on the backend.
// upload API
server.post(
`${basePath}/upload`,
 async (request: any, reply: any) => {

    // * get file infos and app from multipart-form
    const file = await request.file();
    const appId = file.fields.app_id.value; // <-- Here app_id is undefined when file is appended first in the FormData


    // ...UPLOAD ON AWS CODE
}


We can't tell you why that's happening without seeing the server-side code that's causing the problem. It's certainly not default behaviour - the arguments in the FormData can be placed in any order

@Geeogee what are the other variables you are talking about, open network tab of debugger tools and compare the two outputs to find the root cause of the problem!

@NarenMurali For the other variables, I meant all the properties that I append after the file key (in this specific component, for example, is just app_id that is undefined in the backend).

@RoryMcCrossan I’ve updated the post to include how I retrieve app_id on the backend.

node there? It seems like request.file() would target only the files array of the form. Is there a request.form, or maybe request.body...? Btw, on the front-end easier to just get the  element and use new FormData(formElement);

@Geeogee Also please share the code that makes the API call from the front end and how you pass the parameters

@NarenMurali I updated the handleFileUpload and added the upload.service.ts code

@browsermator In this case, however, I need to pass variables that I can't retrieve from the form, so passing the entire form object is not practical

@Geeogee try using multer instead for handing file uploads.

Not sure how "file.fields.app_id.value" would ever work.  The file(s) will be in separate boundary.... but not sure why that works when order is different.  You might also check if removing const has any effect... so:  let form = new FormData();

@browsermator Using let instead of const doesn't solve the problem

not familiar with node server stuff... but it may be a requirement to have the file(s) array last in the request.  Not sure why that would be.... maybe has to do with the streaming of the file.  Is this "fastify"?  I found a similar thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73952900/fastify-multipart-cannot-read-data-fields-username-value

@browsermator Yes, I'm using Fastify. I looked at the thread you linked, and it's the same situation. However, the author of that thread also didn't discover why appending the file first sometimes causes the other appended variables to be undefined.
